# How to play local video in AVPlayer using an array of URL's?

Tags: ios, url, video, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am developing a iOS app and I want to be able to play a local video file when you select a row from a table view. After a cell row is selected, it hen segues to an AVPlayerViewController where the video should be played, however after the segue is performed and the AVPlayerViewController is presented the AVPlayer it contains remains blank. All the controls show but the player renders blank. Is there a reason why the player isn't playing? I've added all my videos to a folder and added that folder of videos to my main bundle, so I'm not sure why the player doesn't play the videos. Any suggestions as to how I could get the player to play and work would be greatly appreciated. I also triggered the segue to the AVPlayerViewController in the storyboard and it segues every time a cell is tapped.

Code where videos are loaded:

```
 import UIKit
 import AVKit
 import AVFoundation

  class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var player = AVPlayer()
var videoURL = [URL]()
var videoUrl = [URL]()
var drillVid = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
videoUrl = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallBBw:Pound.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallBtwLegwPound.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallCrosswPound.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallHiLo.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/OneBallThruHoop.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallIOw:Wiper.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallJuggle.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallInOut.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallWiper.mp4"),URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwpBallOverDribble.mp4")]


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self }
```

Code where player is rendered:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

drillVid = videoUrl[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Code where AVPlayerViewController is shown and it's player should play the video, however nothing plays it's just empty:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  drillVid = videoUrl[indexPath.row]. }


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        if segue.identifier == "playDrill" {
                let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                    drillVid = videoURL[indexPath.row]
                    let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController
                    destination.player = AVPlayer(url: drillVid)
                    destination.player?.play()

                }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BHB DrillVids/TwoBallBBw:Pound.mp4")`

is not how you get a file within your bundle..

It's `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Pound", ofType: "mp4")`

Example:  Add a "video" to your project with .mp4 format. Select the video and in the right panel, make the target your app. This will add the video to your Main-Bundle.

In your story board, add a button. Add an AVPlayerController. Control + Click that button and drag it to the AVPlayerController.

[image]

In the View Controller code, override the function prepareForSegue. Get its destination and set it's `player` to play the video by grabbing the Path to the video..

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as! AVPlayerViewController

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video", ofType: "mp4")!)
        destination.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
        destination.player?.play()
    }

}
```

When you run the code and press the button, it will play the video. Tested it myself on an iPhone 6S, iOS 11.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this doesn't really help solve my question. Unless this is why the player isn't playing?

Comment: @MarkoCain;  You are most likely giving the video player the wrong path.. This gets the correct path for the "Pound" resource and the video player will be able to play that.

Comment: Ok thanks, never said it didn't help! I will try it.

Comment: I added the files like you suggested and the player still remains blank and nothing plays. I get no errors just the player refuses to play.

Comment: @MarkoCain; You're doing something incorrectly. I just made a sample project to test this. It works fine..

Comment: Its still not working, is there a way we can chat or I send you my code because I literally tried what you did step for step and my player is still not playing.

Comment: @MarkoCain; https://mega.nz/#!sNkWxLjb!hZW_0roXGyDE0CD8Hy3pEEvWA1PJeJRR6-g2yf6PMPs  I uploaded the project.

Comment: I figured out the issue! I had a close bracket in the wrong location. Simple error, but you're advice helped nonetheless since I did get the player to work so thank you!!!

Comment: I dont get the close button in the player